# How does Persist and Finality interact with each other?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A player in my pod played [Admiral Brass, Unsinkable](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=642440) which puts a finality counter on his pirate when they enter the battlefield from their graveyard during combat. I had a [Cauldron of Souls](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=152065) which lets me give any number of creatures persist until end of turn which allows them to come back to the battlefield with a -1/-1 counter if they died.

So when a creature with a Finality counter dies would it come back to the battlefield with a -1/-1 counter because of Persist or would it go to exile?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It will be exiled because of the Finality counter.**

Persist will not do anything, because persist is a triggered ability that triggers when a creature goes to the graveyard, while finality is a replacement ability that prevents the creature from ever going to the graveyard in the first place.

> 122.1h One or more finality counters on a permanent create a single replacement effect that stops the permanent from going to the graveyard. That effect is “**If this permanent would be put into a graveyard from the battlefield, exile it instead**.”

> 702.79a Persist is a triggered ability. “Persist” means “**When this permanent is put into a graveyard from the battlefield**, if it had no -1/-1 counters on it, return it to the battlefield under its owner’s control with a -1/-1 counter on it.”